# Dictionary vs. List for Uniqueness and Performance

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, hashset

The following is a theoretical question, but I'd like to know if there's a rule of thumb answer to it

Let's imagine a class that has implemented the `GetHashCode()` and the `Equals()` method.

Thus it can be used as a `Dictionary<T>` key or `HashSet<T>`.

Now I want to check a list of N items against another list of unique M items, if all of the Ns are unique against each other and against any M.

Since they are dictionary-ready, I could simply add all Ms to a dictionary, and then iterate over the Ns and check/add them until I do or do not fail.

Or I could just put the Ms into a `List<T>` and then iterate over the Ns, check for equality and add them to the M list.

I'm looking at this from a performance perspective. Depending on how well-chosen the hash code is, a `ContainsKey()` plus an `Add()` will result in 2 (`GetHashCode()`, `GetHashCode()`) or 4 function calls (`GetHashCode()`, `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()`, `Equals()`).

The For loop on the other hand, will only use 1 function call (if you use the `IEquatable<T>` interface you can use `Contains()`), the `Equals()` call.

But from a writing standpoint, a `Dictionary<T>` or a `HashSet<T>` seems much more intuitive because the code immediately tells you the goal of the author (looking for uniqueness).

Is there a number of M and N that would you make choose one over the other?

Bonus question: If your standard use case doesn't expect a key to be already present, would it be better code to just try to add the key to the `Dictionary<T>` and catch the `ArgumentException` instead of using `ContainsKey()`?

Comment: only one way to find out: make a test example using both techniques and use a stopswatch to get the performance. it will depend on the number of entries but i guess if performance is an issue a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> or a SortedList<TKey,TValue> should outperform in most cases.

Comment: And a link to this obligatory article on performance: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose that you are talking about asymptotic complexity of the algorithm, which means that N and M are quite big. In this case, overhead of calling functions like Equals() and GetHashCode() (assuming they are O(1), of course).

If you want to compare asymptotic complexity of one algorithm against others, then HashSet will give you the best result in general case, because it has O(1) complexity on functions like Contains.

But, you first need to add the elements to hash set. Which can cause array creation of new array and copying references (if we are talking about reference types or values if we are talking about value types).

The same goes for List and Dictionary, they also have O(1) complexity on adding new item when element count is less than some internal capacity and O(n) otherwise.

So, if you have a good hash function and you can't make assumptions about comparing input values between themselves, that can lower the complexity on just comparing them by hand, you should probably go with HashSet.